# Spring boot Load configuration per environment using PropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I'm trying to add authorization to several microservices. Given all the services share similar authorization process, I want to extract the logic to a shared library.

I managed to create library, but I realise all the configurations need to be set in the `application.yml` file in the microservice which calls the library. I don't want to expose some of the configurations at service layer though.

After some searches, I found I could set `@PropertySource("library.properties")` in my library's configuration class to force reading properties from the specified `.properties` file within the library.

The problem now is I want to set different values for different environments, e.g. authorization URL for test and production would be different. How can I configure the file so that the configuration class would read same property value based on active profile (e.g. environment = test/staging/production)?

Comment: For the record, I end up defining `application-{env}.properties` file in the Java library repo. And it can be picked up correctly by the service that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple property files such as "application-environment.yml” in your resource folder. Spring framework picks the right one based on the active profile. 
For example, if you define a “staging” environment and have a staging profile and then your property file should be named as application-staging.yml.